# Combining two separate date fields to one in Tableau

Tags: date, range, tableau-api, calculated-field

I’m trying to combine two separate date fields into one so that I can calculate a defect rate between the two.
I have two date fields:
1.  EndDate
2.  FundingDate
The EndDate field is used to capture the # of units for a particular ‘project’ for a particular month. The FundingDate is used to capture the total # of volume generate for a particular month.

If I create a worksheet using just EndDate and filter to a ‘project’ I’m interested in and COUNTD the # of units, those figures turn out to be accurate for their respective months.

Same goes for the FundingDate, separate worksheet, COUNTD the # of units, figures are accurate for their respective month.

If I try to view the COUNTD of units from a project using the FundingDate, the #’s are off. Same goes for the total volume if I use EndDate trying to find the total volume.

How do I create a Date Dimension that both can pull off of that reflect the correct COUNTD?

Comment: Also, using the Pivot function in Tableau is not an option as the data is not coming from Excel, .TXT, .PDF, etc.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Also, end date has more granularity and funding date has less granularity what data are you trying to retrive?

Comment: I cannot supply data for privacy reason. I’m trying to combine two separate date fields into one so that I can calculate a defect rate between the two. I have two date fields

Comment: Actually combining two date fields, will always a tricky and to suggest on a best approach we need to see sample data not the company data

Comment: this was resolved by creating an external .TXT file with a Master Date list. I then duplicated the original data source and did a cross data base join to the two date fields to the Master Date.

Answer (score 0):

this was resolved by creating an external .TXT file with a Master Date list. I then duplicated the original data source and did a cross data base join to the two date fields to the Master Date

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multipleconnections_troubleshooting.html